# Writing formatted output for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

According to docs for vswprintf: This function Write formatted output using a pointer to a list of arguments.

Does anyone know of functions for native iOS API that can achieve similar effect?

Or, how would you do this?

I know NSString Initwithformat can emulate sprint, but what is the function to emulate vswprintf or even vsprintf?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NSString` equivalent of `vsprintf` is `initWithString:arguments:`, like this:

```
// format has type NSString *
// ap has type va_list
NSString *formattedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:ap];
```

There is no separate wide-character version of `NSString`.  Every `NSString` stores Unicode characters, not bytes.  If you have an array of UTF-16 characters, you can use `+[NSString stringWithCharacters:length:]` to convert it to an `NSString`.

`NSString` thinks the `%s` format string means an array of one-byte character codes, terminated by a zero byte.

`NSString` thinks the `%S` format string means an array of two-byte character codes, terminated by two zero bytes.

On iOS, a `wchar_t` is 4 bytes.  I don't think `NSString` supports the `%ls` format string for an array of `wchar_t`.  [This documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1) doesn't mention using the `l` modifier with the `s` format.  I looked at [the `CFFormatCharsType` case in `__CFStringAppendFormatCore`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-635/CFString.c) and I don't think it supports `%ls`.

If you have an array of `wchar_t`, and it contains UTF-32 character codes, you can create an `NSString` containing the same characters like this:

```
wchar_t *wchars = ...;
unsigned int wcharCount = ...; // number of characters pointed to by wchars

NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:(const void *)wchars
    length:wcharCount * sizeof *wchars
    encoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding];
```

If you want to just use `vswprintf`, you can; iOS supports it.  You need to `#include <wchar.h>` to get its declaration.

Comment: Hi, I tried what you just said with this: NSString *iosString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%ls = %ls" arguments:argListTest]; is returning me with bad access.  This function's purpose is supposed to send in *w_char's in the argListTest.    Is this the correct way?

Comment: Very helpful response, I will try that! The reason I cannot use vswprintf for iOS is because it doesn't support locales other then C(english).  I tried setting set locale("UTF-8"); and it always stays as C.  If I try to use vswprintf with japanese characters as input for example, it will return -1.